# Does the expected value of the derivative of the log likelihood evaluated at a certain parameter always have negative mean?

Tags: probability, statistics

It is well known that the derivative of the log likelihood with respect to the parameter of interest (the score) has zero expected value.

Assuming $f(z;\theta)$ is a probability density function the quick version of the proof (skipping the technicalities in swapping the derivative and the integral) is

$$\int \frac{\partial f(z;\theta)}{\partial \theta}dz=0 \Leftrightarrow \int \frac{f(z;\theta)}{f(z;\theta)} \frac{\partial f(z;\theta)}{\partial \theta}dz=0\Leftrightarrow \int f(z;\theta) \frac{\partial \log f(z;\theta)}{\partial \theta}dz=0$$

I was wondering if taking $\theta_1 > \theta$ the expected value of the score evaluated at $\theta_1$

$$\int f(z;\theta) \frac{\partial \log f(z;\theta_1)}{\partial \theta_1}dz$$

was always negative. I have tried this for the mean and variance of the normal distribution and for the parameter of the exponential distribution and it holds. Here is the derivation for the exponential:

Assume $X \sim exp( \lambda)$.
Take $\lambda_1 > \lambda$
the derivative of the log likelihood of the exponential density with one observation is $$S(\lambda, x):=\frac{\partial }{ \partial \lambda} (\log(\lambda) - \lambda x) = \frac{1}{\lambda} - x$$

So
$$E[S(\lambda_1, X)] = E \left[  \frac{1}{\lambda_1} - X \right] = \frac{1}{\lambda_1} - \frac{1}{\lambda} < 0.$$

does this hold in general?

EDIT: I was working on a proof only for the exponential family of distributions but couldn't quite make it, even a subcase like the exponential family would be interesting to me.

EDIT2: after thinking about this for a while I think an equivalent way to state the problem is: "when is the maximum likelihood estimator unbiased". So, when is it unbiased?

Comment: "Parameters of interest" should really be clearly specified. Do you only need to investigate the scale parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question can be rephrased somewhat into 'does the expected value of the derivative of the log-likelihood always point towards the correct value?' (if it doesn't then you can turn it into a counter example of your hypothesis by optionally flipping the sign of $\theta$).

This won't be true in general, you could for instance come up with a distribution like:

$$
\sin(x + \theta)^2 / (1+x^2)
$$

which is periodic in $\theta$, clearly the derivative at $\theta + 2\pi$  must be equal to the one at $\theta$, and clearly $E_\theta[S(\theta_1, X)] = E_{\theta+2\pi}[S(\theta_1, X)]$ so both can't point to the 'correct' value at the same time.

However having a probability distribution where several $\theta$ are equivalent is clearly not usually the case. So we need to require some kind of 'unimodality'. To see what kind we need it's instructive to pull the derivative outside of the expectation:

$$
\begin{align}
\int f(z;\theta) \frac{\partial \log f(z;\theta_1)}{\partial \theta_1} \,\mathrm{d}z
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1}  \int f(z;\theta) \log f(z;\theta_1) \,\mathrm{d}z
\end{align}
$$

so now we're looking at the (negative) derivative of the cross entropy (which is also the derivative of the Kullback-Leibler divergence), which is a measure of how close the distribution $f(z;\theta_1)$ is to the 'true' distribution $f(z;\theta)$. It's now clear why its derivative is usually pointing the right way, since we'd generally expect the model to get better if the parameters are closer to their actual values.

Anyway from this we can extract, a sufficient, but maybe not necessary condition, which is for the probability distribution to be log concave (i.e. $\log(f(z;\theta_1))$ is concave w.r.t. $\theta_1$), in that case it's expected value

$$
\int f(z;\theta) \log f(z;\theta_1) \,\mathrm{d}z
$$

is also concave, which in particular means that it's derivative is monotonically non-increasing and is $0$ at $\theta_1 = \theta$, this is enough to conclude that $E_{\theta}[S(\theta_1, X)]$ is pointing towards $\theta$.

The exponential distribution and normal distribution are all log-concave w.r.t all their parameters, but keep in mind that most distributions are called log-concave when they're log-concave w.r.t to the value (here $z$) not the parameters (here $\theta_1$).

Comment: Wow! Thanks, this is a great answer! but I think there is an error in the calculation of the derivative of the loglikelihood in the answer by @Alex so "flipping the sign of $\theta$" would not work as a counterexample. Namely I think that $E_{θ_1}(S(θ_2, X)) = - \frac{1}{θ_1} + \frac{1}{θ_2}$ or am I mistaken?

Comment: Also I did not know that if the probability distribution was log concave with respect to the parameter $\theta$ then the expectation would be also concave, could you provide me a reference? Thanks again for the lovely answer, this solves it for me.

Comment: Actually what I'm hinting at is that $E_\theta(S(\theta_1, X))$ should flip sign as well if you flip the sign of $\theta$ (a coordinate transform shouldn't normally affect the expected value, but does flip the sign of $S$), somehow this doesn't happen in Alex's answer which is suspicious.

Comment: On concavity, if $x g(z; \theta_1) + (1-x) g(z; \theta_2) \leq g(z; x \theta_1 + (1-x) \theta_2)$ for all $z$ then this inequality remains true if you take the expected value on both sides, so concavity is preserved w.r.t taking expected values.

Comment: Could you come up with a distribution that is NOT log-concave wrt the parameters? I am trying to find one but to no avail. (aside from the continuous uniform that has other problems).

Comment: The pathological distribution I gave is obviously not log-concave. Most simple distributions seem to be log-concave, but things like Student's t might not be.

Comment: "and is $0$ at $ \theta_1 = \theta$ ", I am having a doubt as to why this is. I don't think the true parameter necessarily denotes a maximum, I mean $\theta$ does not come out of a maximum likelihood procedure it's just fixed a priori. What am I missing? Sorry to bother.

Comment: That's actually not an entirely trivial point, but it follows from the fact that you're basically looking at the derivative of the KL-divergence (with an additional minus sign) which is non-negative and is 0 precisely when $\theta_1 = \theta$. So $\theta_1 = \theta$ is necessarily a global maximum (although it may not be unique). Therefore the derivative (if it exists) must be 0 at $\theta_1 = \theta$, because the alternative suggests that the KL-divergence would become ever so slightly negative which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}$This is not true in general. For example, take$$
f(x; θ) = -θ \e^{θx}, \quad x > 0
$$
where $θ \in (-∞, 0)$, then by your calculation,$$
E_{θ_1}(S(θ_2, X)) = \frac{1}{θ_1} - \frac{1}{θ_2}, \quad \forall θ_1, θ_2 \in (-∞, 0)
$$
and $E_{θ_1}(S(θ_2, X)) > 0$ for $θ_1 < θ_2 < 0$.

Comment: While this answer helps me and I like it it is also kind of unsatisfactory in the sense that If I require the parameter to be strictly positive could a counterexample still arise? This is not meant in as a critique in any sense, more of a critique of my original question.

Comment: I think there in a sign error in the calculations.